# 'Unable to find a suitable outpit format for '-ss' in FFmpeg

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg

Sort of at a loss here. I'm trying to extract a single frame from a video to use as a preview image using FFmpeg on an Ubuntu server. Dozens of guides, wikis, and StackExchange answers tell me to format the command like this:

```
ffmpeg —ss 00:00:05 -i path/video.mp4 —frames:v 1 -vf crop=640:520 path/image.jpg
```

However, when I try to run this command, FFmpeg returns me this error:

```
[NULL @ 0x516d2a0] Unable to find a suitable output format for '—ss'
—ss: Invalid argument
```

What could be going wrong? It seems like FFmpeg isn't recognizing its own command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How is `—ss:` an `Invalid argument` to `ffmpeg`?

Your command as written has an emdash (`—`)<sup>1</sup> instead of a dash (`-`), replace that and it works:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:05 -i path/video.mp4 -frames:v 1 -vf crop=640:520 path/image.jpg
```

*(note that the `frames` argument also had an incorrect em dash - be careful when copying and pasting!)*

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> See http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/em-dash.html for example<sup>2</sup></sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> You may also be interested in the venerable [en dash](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/en-dash.html), and a [comparison between the two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash_versus_em_dash)</sup>

Comment: Hah, beat me to my own answer! Yep, I just discovered that myself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good stuff! I think it's an *em* dash, as opposed to an *en* dash, but I won't quibble :)

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780736/ffmpeg-unable-to-find-a-suitable-output-format-for-i?rq=1

For those who don't want to click away, the problem is that an emdash (–) is not the same thing as a hyphen (-).